# rails controller do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

Hi i have a rails application,this is controller

```
class StreamsController < ApplicationController

  def conversations
    stream_responder do
      @stream = Stream::Conversations.new(current_user, :max_time => max_time)
      @stream_json = PostConversationPresenter.collection_json(@stream.stream_posts, current_user)
    end
  end

def stream_responder(&block)
    yield
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        gon.stream = @stream_json
        render :nothing => true, :layout => "post"
      end
      format.mobile {authenticate_user!; render 'layouts/main_stream' }
      format.json {render :json => @stream_json }
    end
  end
end
```

i would like to what do it means `stream_responder do` and `gon.stream`

Answer (score 0):

`def conversation` is a action and `def stream_responder` is a custom function written which takes block as input and performs some action. `gon.stream` is part of gon gem which helps putting values of the variable in the views as javascript varaible so that you can later reference them in your javascript files. This link will help you understand about gon gem [Gon Gem](http://github.com/gazay/gon)

Answer (score 0):

`stream_responder do ... end` calls the `stream_responder` method passing in a block. You can see the method signature accepts a block with `&block` and calls that block with `yield`.

See Shreyas' answer too